# getting nulls when concatenating string columns in pyspark. Why?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this super simple dataframe:

```
rc1.show(5)
rc1.printSchema()
+--------+-----------+
|      ID|Case number|
+--------+-----------+
|11034701|   JA366925|
|11227287|   JB147188|
|11227583|   JB147595|
|11227293|   JB147230|
|11227634|   JB147599|
+--------+-----------+
only showing top 5 rows

root
 |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Case number: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to add a new column that is just the concatenation of the "Case number" column and "aaa", so I'm using this to do that:

```
rc2 = rc1.withColumn("Case numberxx", col("Case number") + "aaa")
rc2.show(5)
```

However, I can't, for the life of me, understand why my new column is full of nulls:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|      ID|Case number|Case numberxx|
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|11034701|   JA366925|         null|
|11227287|   JB147188|         null|
|11227583|   JB147595|         null|
|11227293|   JB147230|         null|
|11227634|   JB147599|         null|
+--------+-----------+-------------+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know pyspark, but maybe it should be `rc1.col("Case number")`?

Comment: Pyspark doesn't concatenate strings with `+` operator. Use `concat`

Answer (score -1):

ok guys, this worked fine:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat, lit

rc2 = rc1.withColumn("Case numberxx", concat(col("Case number"), lit("aaa")))
rc2.show(5)

+--------+-----------+-------------+
|      ID|Case number|Case numberxx|
+--------+-----------+-------------+
|11034701|   JA366925|  JA366925aaa|
|11227287|   JB147188|  JB147188aaa|
|11227583|   JB147595|  JB147595aaa|
|11227293|   JB147230|  JB147230aaa|
|11227634|   JB147599|  JB147599aaa|
+--------+-----------+-------------+
```

However, I can't quite make out why this is null:

```
col("Case number") + lit("aaa")
```

but this is ok

```
concat(col("Case number"), lit("aaa"))
```